# How to execute all tests in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, testing, selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

I'm trying run all tests from my testsuite, but PHPUnit not found the tests when I run command `phpunit`. I config testsuite in phpunit.xml.

phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="true"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="./bootstrap.php"
         cacheTokens="false"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         forceCoversAnnotation="false"
         mapTestClassNameToCoveredClassName="false"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnError="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         stopOnIncomplete="false"
         stopOnSkipped="false"
         strict="false"
         verbose="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="All Tests">
            <directory suffix="*.php">.</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

bootstrap.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/WebTestCase.php');
```

WebTestCase.php

```
<?php

define('TEST_BASE_URL', 'http://localhost:8080');

class WebTestCase extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{

    protected function setUp() {
        $this->setBrowser('*firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl(TEST_BASE_URL);
        $this->setHost('localhost');
        $this->setTimeOut(30);
    }
}
```

TestPage.php

```
class TestPage extends WebTestCase
{

    public function testTitle()
    {
        $this->open("/");
        $title = $this->getTitle();
        $this->assertEquals('Home', $title);
    }
}
```

If I run phpunit passing file test, as `phpunit TestPage.php`, is ok.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html):

> Note If you point the PHPUnit command-line test runner to a directory
>   it will look for *Test.php files.

It is good practice to have your testing classes with this format. However, if that's not an option for you, you can change this behaviour creating the `phpunit.xml` file and setting it up properly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<phpunit>
<testsuite name='Name your suite'>
    <directory suffix=".php">/path/to/files</directory>
</testsuite>
</phpunit>
```

Note that I removed the `*`. In theory, phpunit should go through the directory and execute all files with `.php` at the end of the file.

I think that if you remove the `*` and set the correct path, it should work.

Comment: thanks for answer, was helpful. The sufix "Test.php" or removed the "*" both worked.