# How to make PHPUnit run all the tests?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

As a tester, I want security and reliability by using PHPUnit to test my code.

Presently, PHPUnit only passes the first of eleven tests. It then abandons the remaining tests, with no message.

```
>>>  vendor/bin/phpunit [path to my test]
<<<  .

[No message from PHPUnit after the first '.'.]
```

What I've tried:

- Removing PHPUnit, clearing my cache (`composer clearcache`), and reinstalling PHPUnit (`composer install`)
- Making sure each test docstring has `@test` in it
- Using \test[a-zA-Z]\ as function names
- Using phpunit --filter [name of a test that didn't run]
- Changing PHPUnit from v8.4.3 to v8.2 (`composer update`)
- Adding `dd("Hi")` to the first, second, and third tests. (It shows up with #1 and #2, but not #3)

What I've read:

- (Stuff with the same search terms but a different problem) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073239/how-to-execute-all-tests-in-phpunit), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414125/how-do-i-run-all-my-phpunit-tests), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086594/laravel-5-2-testing-test-is-not-running).
- The most helpful I've read is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611346/how-to-force-composer-to-reinstall-a-library).
- Also other pages.

[My test suite](https://gist.github.com/Crowbrammer/9bc3559ddda178984cad19bdf11c0fc7).

[My phpunit.xml file](https://gist.github.com/Crowbrammer/d4de7fec4eaf81e95b726754616c689b)

My specs:

- Laravel 6.5.6
- PHPUnit 8.4.3

How do I make PHPUnit run all eleven tests?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why did the tests not run? I don't know.

But I do know how I got them to run again:

- Delete the whole working directory

My team uses Docker. Something about Docker tracks the original directory. Even if you delete it and put a new directory there with the same name, it appears it's linked to the actual folder and not the location. So putting a new folder in the same spot with the same name doesn't work. So I need to restart the Docker thing.

- Stop all the Docker processes: `docker kill $(docker ps -q)`
- Remove all containers: `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`

Get the original stuff back up. These steps are standard in Laravel apps.

- Clone the directory from BitBucket/GitHub/etc.
- In the directory, run `docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d`
- `composer install`
- `npm i`
- `php artisan migrate`
- `php artisan db:seed`